# Why strings are not read correctly using easydict？

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, python-packaging

I use the easydict library to set the configurations, but when I store the configuration as strings, it turns the string into a list of the string itself, as follows:

```
from easydict import EasyDict
conf = EasyDict()
conf.name = 'CD Group'
print(conf.name)

> ['CD Group']    # a list
```

But what I hope to achieve is:

```
> CD Group    # string type
```

Why is it like this?
Thanks for any feedback!

[easydict source](https://github.com/makinacorpus/easydict)

An interesting point is that when I pass the configuration from the argparse into the easydict, the type doesn't get an error, as follow:

```
conf.file_name = args.file_name    # --file_name input.xlsx
print(conf.file_name)

> input.xlsx
```

Comment: @eshirvana But this is not the case with other type such as int or float.

Comment: then maybe you passed a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at `__setattr__`

```
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if isinstance(value, (list, tuple)):
            value = [self.__class__(x)
                     if isinstance(x, dict) else x for x in value]
        elif isinstance(value, dict) and not isinstance(value, self.__class__):
            value = self.__class__(value)
```

as you can see in `__setattr__` method , if you pass a variable as list or tuple , you get a list, if not you get the original type back.

and I don't have the problem you are mentioning :

```
conf = EasyDict()
conf.name = 'CD Group'
conf.name2 = ['CD Group']
print(conf.name , conf.name2, sep='\n')
```

output:

```
>>
CD Group
['CD Group']
```

Comment: I finally figured it out, I put a comma at the end of the sentence and it reads as a list. Thank you!